# JPA insert bad number of parameters in a relation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a DB with a table Group and another table Participants. One participant can be in many groups and a group can have many participants.

Tables are like this:

Participant table

```
| group_id (PK) | user_id (PK) | date | is_admin |
|---------------|--------------|------|----------|
```

Value `date` has not default value and `isAdmin` is 0.

Group table is:

```
| group_id | more_data |
|----------|-----------|
```

So I've created the relation into Java like this (this is the Group object):

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="tParticipants",
        joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="groupId", updatable=false, insertable=false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="groupId"),
                @JoinColumn(name="userId")
        })
    private List<Participant> participants;
```

This relation (if I'm not mistaken) do:

- Join the current entity (group) with table Participant.
- Uses the column `groupId` for current table to map with `groupId` and `userId` from table Participant.

Entity Participant is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tParticipants")
@IdClass(ParticipantKey.class)
public class Participant {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("groupId")
    private Integer groupId = null;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private Integer userId = null;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private Long date;

    @JsonProperty("isAdmin")
    private Boolean isAdmin;
```

And ParticipantKey is:

```
private Integer groupId = null;
private Integer userId = null;
```

Well, this code allows project to start, so I think values are mapped correctly, but maybe not.

But the problem is when I try to insert a new Group. I want to add a new Group with `isAdmin = 1` and `date = CurrentTime`. So in Java I do something like this:

```
// Create a Participant
Participant participant = new Participant();
participant.setUserId(userId);
participant.setIsAdmin(true);
participant.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
// Add to a list
List<Participant> participants = new List<Participant>();
participants.add(participant);
// Add into group object
group.setParticipants(participants);
```

But when I do `groupDao.save(group)` it throws an exception:

`Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)`

Logs says that JPA try to do:

```
insert into t_participants (group_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [26]
binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [null]
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Value 26 is the `group_id`, 1 is the `user_id` but I don't know what is null and also, the query needs `date` value because it doesn't have a default one.

So, what's the problem? How to mapping values to create the object and JPA create the query automatically something like:

```
insert into t_participants (group_id, user_id, date, is_admin) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is participant and user same here?

Comment: Please share us `date` and `isAdmin` properties declaration in the `Participant` entity

Comment: It feels like this `Participant` entity is a mapping table between two entities like `Group` and `User`, am I correct?

Comment: No, a `Group` has participants, but participants are not related with `User`. There is no relation or FK in JPA or SQL between `User` and `Participant`. Of course column `user_id` is used in some queries to Join with `User` table, but there is not an implicit relation.

Comment: But how this would be many to many relation if there is no mapping involved between `Group` and `Participant`, it sounds more like `OneToMany` from `Group` side.

Comment: `Group` and `Participant` has relation. I've put all relation in `Group` object. Have I missing something in `Participant` class?

Comment: For many to many, we need to have an entity between two entities which is the joining two entities if we make a bidirectional relation in JPA but if we go with unidirectional (which looks like your case), hibernate creates a joining table behind the scenes, so in this case it is expecting 3 fields in that table i.e groupId from Group and groupId, paticipantId from Participant because of inverse join.

Comment: @J.F. You miss `@Entity` on your Participant Class. Can you please add it and inform us

Comment: @code_mechanic nice explanation, make sense. How can I handle that to insert values correctly?

Comment: @Boug Is added in my code. OP edited to add too.

Comment: I will add as an answer.

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong here. 1. `Participant` has a `groupId` which, according to your mapping should appear in the join table. And there also should map to the `Group`. This does not allow for an M:N relationship, because the group is already fixed. 2. your join table `tParticipants` is identical to the table used for `Participant`. This does not work, because they have to be two different things, because they contain different data. 3. The insert goes to `t_participants` but all configuration uses the table `tParticipants. Something is off here as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JensSchauder. There is not join table created in SQL (only `t_participants` and `t_group`). Also JPA `tParticipants` and `t_participants` in SQL is the same. The entity is the table. Also if you think there is an "architecture/design" problem tell me too.

Comment: there is no join table because of point #2 I made above. Give it a different name and it will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Unidirectional Mapping

Assuming there are two entities here one is `Group` and other `Participant` which has many to many relation.

There are certain ways to map many to many relation but I won't add all possible ways but instead will share the approach which I think is the best one.

So, let's look at the current approach which is followed here (I will correct it a little bit because that's already having issues and we will see what is the issue).

Group entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "t_group_participants",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "participantId")
            }
    )
    private List<Participant> participants;
}
```

And the Participant entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "participants")
public class Participant {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer participantId;
}
```

Omitted the getter/setter here, now notice the name attribute of `@JoinTable` annotation here, it is the name of table which will map the two entities and this relation is unidirectional relation as per hibernate. So, what's happening behind the scenes

```
//t_groups table

| group_id (PK) | name |
|---------------|------|

// t_participants table
| partcipant_id (pk) | name |
| -------------------| ---- |

//t_group_participants
| group_id | participant_id |
| -------- | -------------- |
```

Just notice the third table, it may not be created by you but since its unidirectional relations marked as `@ManyToMany` with `@JoinTable`, hibernate will create one.

In the question, you are thinking the `Participant` entity or `t_participants` table will act like one (at least from question it appears)  but that's not mapping table, it is mapped to `Participant` which are being added into groups.

Since, you have defined `inverseColumns` with two foreign keys, hibernate is trying to insert 3 values into this table (one field coming from group table i.e group_id), although table was not meant for that (it is participant table).

So, if you can provide different name, something like in code example above it will work (little table structure should make things more clear), but this would have few issues:

1. Extra queries will be fired by hibernate to save into mapping table (check logs below, notice extra delete call)
2. Approach will not work when you have more than foreign keys i.e is_admin, date etc.

**Extra query log**

```
Hibernate: select group0_.id as id1_17_0_ from t_groups group0_ where group0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into participants (participantId) values (?)
Hibernate: delete from t_group_participants where groupId=?
Hibernate: insert into t_group_participants (groupId, participantId) values (?, ?)
```

#### Bidirectional mapping

I would suggest you create bidirectional mapping using a one more entity `GroupParticipants`, this time we will provide the mapping ourselves instead of hibernate creating one.

```
@Embeddable
public class ParticipantId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Integer groupId;
    @Column(name = "participant_id")
    private Integer participantId;

    public ParticipantId() {}

    public ParticipantId(Integer groupId, Integer participantId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.participantId = participantId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_group_participants")
public class GroupParticipant {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ParticipantId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("groupId")
    private Group group;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("participantId")
    private Participant participant;
    @Column(name = "is_admin", nullable = false)
    private boolean isAdmin;

    public GroupParticipant() { }

    public GroupParticipant(Group group, Participant participant) {
        this.group = group;
        this.participant = participant;
        this.id = new ParticipantId(group.getId(), participant.getParticipantId());
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

What I have done is, I have joined the the `Group` with `GroupParticipant` using `@OneToMany` relationship (similar way participant can have the mapping with GroupParticipant, if needed). `GroupParticipant` having `@ManyToOne` relation with both `Group` and `Participant`, so `Group` and `Participant` have many-to-many relationship(although indirect) among them.

The `@MapsId` will map both `group` and `participant` property to `id` of class  which is embeddable object. So it will share both `group_id` and `participant_id` from two parent entities and create the composite key in our mapping table.

And we will change the mapping in `Group` entity because which is parent here and add a convenience API method to keep 3 entities in synch (because of bidirectional relationships)

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<GroupParticipant> participants = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addParticipant(Participant p) {
        GroupParticipant gP = new GroupParticipant(this, p);
        gp.setIsAdmin(true);
        participants.add(gP);
    }
```

Notice, that `add` function receiving `Participant` as entity not `GroupParticipant`.

If you check the logs now, you would see queries like

```
Hibernate: select group0_.id as id1_17_0_ from t_groups group0_ where group0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into participants (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into t_group_participants (is_admin, group_id, participant_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Also, you can add extra parameters to the mapping table as required i.e isAdmin

So, one extra `delete` is not executed here, if you need to return the participants from group, you could modify your getter like this

```
public List<Participant> getParticipants() {
        return participants.stream().map(GroupParticipant::getParticipant).collect(toList());
}
```